# How can I stop QuizUp from using up so much of my storage space?

Tags: applications

After a few weeks of usage the apps settings show that QuizUp is taking up several hundred megabytes of local data storage.

What is causing this and how can I prevent it? Clearing the app cache won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** After recent updates this problem does not seem to occur anymore, so this answer is probably obsolete.

---

**Overview**

This is caused by the results screen. Quizup will download each match question as a screenshot instead of rendering it on the client's side. Not only does this result in a lot of additional mobile data usage but it also takes up a lot of space on your device because all screenshots are cached. Unfortunately there does not seem to be any limit to this caching and there is no way to turn it off from the app itself. Fortunately there are two workarounds.

**Workaround 1: Clearing the screenshots cache manually**

Navigate to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.quizup.core/` on your file explorer of choice and delete the `screenshots` folder. This will only affect the screenshots cache. As oposed to clearing the app data from the **apps** menu all user data, e.g. your account and settings, will be preserved.

**Workaround 2: Disabling screenshot storage**

Navigate to `/sdcard/Android/data/com.quizup.core/` with your favorite file manager. Delete the `screenshots` folder. Then proceed to create a new empty file called `screenshots`.

From now on no screenshots will be saved locally. They might still be retrieved and continue to cause high mobile data usage, though.

The downside to this method: The *Match Questions* section on the result page will stop working.

**Sources**

http://www.reddit.com/r/QuizUp/comments/2059bb/data_usage/